# Tensorflow 2.0 `tf.multiply` method gives unexpected results

Tags: python, tensorflow, broadcasting

I am bit confused about output shape of this operation

```py
>>> eps = tf.random.uniform((3))
>>> images = tf.random.normal((3, 28, 28, 1))
>>> output = eps * images
>>> output.get_shape()
(3, 28, 28, 3)
```

I want this to multiply every single scalar in `eps` with each image of shape `(28, 28, 1)`  in  images to get the output shape  `(3, 28, 28, 1)`

Something like this

```py
>>> output = []
>>> output.append(eps[0] * images[0])
>>> output.append(eps[1] * images[1])
>>> output.append(eps[2] * images[2])
>>> output = tf.convert_to_tensor(output)
>>> output.get_shape()
(3, 28, 28, 1)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html) (the link is from NumPy documentation, but it works the same way in TensorFlow). If you want to "match" the single dimension of `eps` to the first dimension of `images`, you need to add extra singleton dimensions to `eps` so the broadcasting works as you expect:

```py
eps = tf.random.uniform((3))
# Add dimensions for broadcasting
eps = tf.reshape(eps, [-1, 1, 1, 1])
output = eps * images
print(output.get_shape())
# (3, 28, 28, 1)
```

Alternatively, you can directly create `eps` with that shape:

```py
eps = tf.random.uniform((3, 1, 1, 1))
```